# Is this proper way to resolve circular typedef dependency?

Tags: c, header, circular-dependency

I have code with circular dependency.

old a.h file:

```
#ifndef A_H
#define A_H

#include "b.h"

typedef struct {
    b_t *test;
} a_t;

#endif
```

old b.h file:

```
#ifndef B_H
#define B_H

#include "a.h"

typedef struct {
    a_t *test;
} b_t;

#endif
```

I've just wanted to know if my solution is "proper way" to solve that problem. I want produce nice and clear code.

new a.h file:

```
#ifndef A_H
#define A_H

#include "b.h"

typedef struct b_t b_t;

struct a_t {
    b_t *test;
};

#endif
```

new b.h file:

```
#ifndef B_H
#define B_H

#include "a.h"

typedef struct a_t a_t;

struct b_t {
    a_t *test;
};

#endif
```

Comment: Google for "incomplete type".

Comment: There is one argument for using structs rather than obfuscating code with typedefs.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

A problem with your approach is that the `typedef` for `a_t` is in the `b.h`, and vice versa.

A somewhat cleaner way would be to keep your `typedef` with the struct, and use structure tags in the declarations, like this:

a.h

```
#ifndef A_H
#define A_H

struct b_t;

typedef struct a_t {
    struct b_t *test;
} a_t;

#endif
```

b.h

```
#ifndef B_H
#define B_H

struct a_t;

typedef struct b_t {
    struct a_t *test;
} b_t;

#endif
```